# OpenSSL des-ede3 not producing same output as test vector implies it should be

Tags: des, openssl, 3des, test-vectors

I'm encrypting one of the standard TDEA/3DES/DES-EDE test vectors with openssl:

```
<?php
$key = pack('H*', '0123456789ABCDEF' . '23456789ABCDEF01' . '456789ABCDEF0123');

$result = openssl_encrypt('The quick brown fox jump', 'des-ede3', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);

echo chunk_split(bin2hex($result), 16, ' ');
```

(des-ede3 is ecb mode)

This gives `1ccf23869d09333e cce21c8112256fe6 68d5c05dd9b6b900` as the result.

But the test vector for TDEA in ECB mode in [NIST SP 800-67 Appendix B.1](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-67-Rev1/SP-800-67-Rev1.pdf#page=27) states that the output should be `A826FD8CE53B855F CCE21C8112256FE6 68D5C05DD9B6B900`.

So what's up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there's an error in the test vector.

The text of Appendix B.1 states:

> P1 = “The quic” = 5468652071756663

... which is incorrect.

The hex encoding of `The quic` is actually `5468652071756963` (note the transposition of the `i`/`69` to an `f`/`66` in the encoding.

e.g. encrypting the test vector as intended:

```
$ echo -n 'The quick brown fox jump' | openssl  des-ede3 -nosalt -nopad -K '0123456789ABCDEF23456789ABCDEF01456789ABCDEF0123'  | xxd -c 8 -ps
1ccf23869d09333e
cce21c8112256fe6
68d5c05dd9b6b900
```

... and encrypting the test vector as hex encoded:

```
$ echo -n 'The qufck brown fox jump' | openssl  des-ede3 -nosalt -nopad -K '0123456789ABCDEF23456789ABCDEF01456789ABCDEF0123'  | xxd -c 8 -ps
a826fd8ce53b855f
cce21c8112256fe6
68d5c05dd9b6b900
```

It looks like this error has been in NIST SP 800-67 since [version 1](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/sp/2004/SP800_67.pdf) in 2004.

Comment: Now that's just funny, finding a typo in one of the DES test vectors, and an evil one at that `666` indeed :)